# Plot 3D Object consisting of many Hexahedra with Gnuplot

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, polygon

I want to plot a 3D object that looks like this:

[image: 3D object]

Although my object is not a simple cube, it consists of several 2D layers that are stacked on top of one other:

[image: 2D layer]

The 2D layers consist of many quadrilaterals, thus the 3D object will consist of hexahedra.

It's easy to plot the 2D layers with the command `splot` in Gnuplot by plotting the two families of grid lines independently.

Is there an easy way to generate a 3D representation like in the first image from this data given any number of 2D layers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but as I understand you want to draw cubes or cuboids which look like they consist out of smaller cubes or cuboids.

The simplest way with gnuplot which I've found (so far) is the following. Maybe there are simpler ways and maybe even some ways to plot it with gnuplot<5.2.0.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### draw segmented cuboid
reset session

set view equal xyz
set pm3d depthorder border lc "black" 
set hidden3d
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "white")
set key noautotitle
unset colorbox
unset border
unset tics

I  = 5     # repetition in x
J  = 7     # in y
K  = 10    # in z
si = 1     # scaling factor for x
sj = 1     # for y
sk = 1     # for z

splot sample        [u=0:I:1][v=0:J:1] '++' u (si*$1):(sj*$2):(0)     w pm3d, \
                    [u=0:I:1][v=0:J:1] '++' u (si*$1):(sj*$2):(sk*K)  w pm3d, \
      for [i=0:I:I] [u=0:J:1][v=0:K:1] '++' u (si*i) :(sj*$1):(sk*$2) w pm3d, \
      for [j=0:J:J] [u=0:I:1][v=0:K:1] '++' u (si*$1):(sj*j) :(sk*$2) w pm3d
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

And as animation... (change the viewing angle and create PNGs in a loop and save as GIF with ScreenToGif)

[image]